# (Excel) How to test multiple values in a single cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to find the effect three inputs (x1,x2,x3) have on the output (y) of a system defined in Excel. Each input can only be fed into the system via a single cell (see [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36A85.png)). Inserting list variables (e.g. A1:A20) only outputs ###########. I have looked into the What If Analysis and it requires the formula to be definable in one cell, which is not the case for this system.

Being very new to Excel I am wondering if it is possible to insert a list into a single cell and output corresponding outputs to multiple cells. Any other solutions to test multiple values in a single cell in Excel would also be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit: [Example Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36A85.png)
Edit: Clarity

Comment: Please include mock ups of your data and expected output

Comment: I am unsure of what the output should look like as this is just preliminary testing, and the input data can simply be [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: Then mock up an example test situation.  Unless you know what you want, how can we answer the question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/v7TtJQZ
Here's an example solution. The inputs are inserted into the system via a single cell which calculates the output across 8 sheets. Currently, I have to type each value into each cell to get the corresponding output

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **A2** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,",",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

With a small modification to the formula. the data could also be parsed row-wise.